# problems with custom class and sort()

Tags: python, sorting

I made a custom class as an exercise, a deck of cards. I have a function that can shuffle it with the `random.shuffle()` function, but I can't seem to get `sort()` working, I know I can just rebuild the deck, but that doesn't work if I have removed cards from the deck before I sort it. Does the `sort()` and `sorted()` need more than a `__lt__` defined?

```
import random

class Card:
    """ Represents a card using a suit and a rank
    suits are Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades represented by 0, 1, 2, 3
    the ranks are 1 to 13 for Ace, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King"""

    def __init__(self, rank=2, suit=1):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    suit_names = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    rank_names = [None, 'Ace', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                 '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s' %(Card.rank_names[self.rank], 
                            Card.suit_names[self.suit])

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.suit, self.rank < other.suit, other.rank

class Deck:
    """ Representing a deck of cards, containing one of each card """

    def __init__(self):
        self.new_deck()

    def new_deck(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                card = Card(rank, suit)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for card in self.cards:
            res.append(str(card))
        return '\n'.join(res)

    def pop_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def sort(self):
        self.cards.sort()


deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
deck.sort()
print(deck)
```

Python will print a randomised and the `deck.sort()` just doesn't work

Comment: `__lt__` should return a `bool` which `self.suit, self.rank < other.suit, other.rank` doesn't do... You probably want `self.rank < other.rank` or similar depending on how/if you want to order suits...

Comment: As a side comment, you have 15 elements in the `rank_names` list: `None` for index 0 and 14 additional ones. I think you should remove `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `__lt__` method is not returning a `bool`, try the following:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return (self.suit, self.rank) < (other.suit, other.rank)
```

The order of the elements inside the `tuple` may get swapped if this does not give the order you wanted to:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return (self.rank, self.suit) < (other.rank, other.suit)
```